# my spring security code is not using the static resources like css,js and images folder

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to access static resource in jsp that i am using in spring security...but it is not accessing those static resources need your ..valuable suggestions ..i am new in springs security ....

my dispacher-servlet is...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.nufame" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />

<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>


<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}    
</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

my security.xml is..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">
 <!-- Non secure URLs -->
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/index" 
    authentication-failure-url="/fail2login" />
    <security:logout invalidate-session="true"
        logout-success-url="/logout" />


    <security:access-denied-handler
        error-page="/403" />
</security:http>
<security:http pattern="/css/**" security="none" />


<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>

        <!-- <security:user-service> <security:user name="dineshonjava" password="sweety" 
            authorities="ROLE_USER" /> </security:user-service> -->
        <security:jdbc-user-service
            data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="select username, password, active from users where username=?"
            authorities-by-username-query="select us.username, ur.authority from users us, user_roles ur 
          where us.user_id = ur.user_id and us.username =?  " />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

my web.xml is...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
 <servlet>
<servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
<listener-class>
              org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>
        /WEB-INF/sdnext-*.xml,
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

 <filter>
 <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
 <filter-class>
              org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
            </filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

please help i AM new in spring security ..

thanks in advance....

Comment: May be that's help you :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476004/unable-to-allow-static-resources-in-spring-security-3

Comment: i tried this one ..but did not get ..the access of static resource..sorry

Answer (score 0):

In dispatcher-servlet, add resources using `<mvc:resources>`, e.g.:
`<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/">` 
And also don't forget to add these lines in top `<bean: ...>` :
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
...
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd

Comment: thanks..but when i am using this and getting resource not found.....with....this error..nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:resources'.

Comment: Did you include dependency (i hope you are using Maven) for 'spring-webmvc' ?

Comment: nope..i am not using dependency(maven) for this..:P..is it not possible to access static resource.i do not think so..u have some idea pls reply...

Comment: I hope, you should download and then add 'spring-webmvc.jar' package to your project's build path.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [How to use static resources like js, css?](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Откройте доступ к папкам всех статических ресурсов в моём случае это "/assets/**", "/fragments/**", "/node_modules/**", "/stylus/**"
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                    .antMatchers("/signin", "/assets/**", "/fragments/**", "/node_modules/**", "/stylus/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin((form) -> form
                    .loginPage("/signin").defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                    .permitAll()
            )
            .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll());
    return http.build();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm0l1.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).